# The charset attribute on the script element is obsolete

Tags: html, web, twitter, hyperlink, embed

I am trying to embed a follow me twitter button on my website but Html checker says;

Warning: The charset attribute on the script element is obsolete.
From line 21, column 141; to line 21, column 216

```
eacher</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></scri
```

I copied the link straight from twitter developer so I don't know why this error.

Comment: It’s not an error, it’s a warning; it should work just fine. Are you having a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that charset attribute...don't ignore it, remove it

The warning will not show again.